# Reorder bootstrap stacking order

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a query regarding Bootstrap grids.  I have a grid, imagine Excel, that has rows 1 and 2 and columns A, B and C in desktop browser mode.

[desktop to stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsMwi.jpg)

I want to reorder the stacked 'cells' in mobile mode to be A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2 order (top to bottom).  I've looked at the pull and push classes but it doesn't do the above.  Can anyone advise how to achieve it please?

I've found other similar answers but nothing that matches my issue exactly.

Thanks,

LB

Comment: The push and pull classes only work on elements that are actually displayed next to each other in the row. The easiest solution would be flexbox' `order` property - but you might need to modify the column styling a bit for that to work.

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40852891/5236174)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this structure. You need to make 3 columns and inside each columns add full width columns in a row.  So in smaller screen it starts stacking from 1st column to last column.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            A1  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            A2  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            B1  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            B2  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            C1  
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            C2  
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. You are welcome.  Thanks for accepting as answer. I don't mind if you up vote it as well. ;)